# regular expression: How to set two conditions at the same time?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner learning web-scraping. Here's a question about how to use regular expression to exert two condition at the time. I have done some researches and learned the code supposes should be (condition 1 +) (condition2) but I can't figure out why it didn't work for me.

Here is the website I want to web scrape from:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_Memorial_Prize_laureates_in_Economics

I tried to use re.search and loop to exert only names of laureates since I found the pattern is : start with `\wiki\` and `Firstname_Lastname`.

ex.

```
/wiki/Paul_Krugman
```

My logic is try to set two conditions with regular expression.

```
all_urls_regex＿findname=[]    
for url in soup.find_all('a',
{'href':re.compile(r'/wiki+')}): 
# make sure it starts with /wiki
 all_urls_regex_findname.append(url.get('href'))
```

```
for url in soup.find_all('a',
                         {'href':re.compile(r'\_+')}): 
                             # make sure there's a  underline)

`all_urls_regex_findname_1.append(url.get('href'))`
```

`(r'/wiki+')` try to exert url starts with wiki
`(r' _+' )`try to exert names (pattern is Firstname_Lastname)

Above two run well respectively.But what I want is the 'and' logic
so I tried to run two condition at the same time

```
`all_urls_regex＿findname_2=[]    
for url in soup.find_all('a',
                         {'href':re.compile(r'/wiki+')(r'\_+')}):`
all_urls_regex_findname.append(url.get('href'))
# but it didn't work, the result is a empty set.
```

Could anyone give me some hints what's going on with my code?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can try getting the lists of the two conditions individually using find_all, and then use the list comprehension: `common_elements = [x for x in list1 if x in list2]` to get a list of the common elements.

Comment: don't you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have to put all in one string in `compile()` - ie `compile(r"/wiki/.*_+.*")` -  BTW: `( )` is not part of `regex` expression but normal function execution. So you have `regex`: `r'/wiki+'` and `r' _+'` not `(r'/wiki+')`and `(r' _+' )`

Comment: Got it @shanylong tks

Comment: Ah i see, will try again! Thank you @furas

Answer (score 1):

To get links I could use

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^/wiki/[A-Z][a-z]*_[A-Z][a-z]*$')
```

but this still gets links like

```
/wiki/United_States
```

so first I would use other function to get only `<table>` (or event column in table) with needed links

---

**EDIT:** it has problem with `/wiki/Bengt_R._Holmstr%C3%B6m` (`Bengt Holmström`) which has two `_` in link and his name has native char `ö` converted in link to `%C3%B6`

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_Memorial_Prize_laureates_in_Economics')
soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

pattern = re.compile(r'^/wiki/[A-Z][a-z]*_[A-Z][a-z]*$')

all_tables = soup.find_all('table')

all_items = all_tables[1].find_all('a', {'href': pattern})
for item in all_items:
    print(item['href'], '|', item['title'])
```

Result:

```
/wiki/Ragnar_Frisch | Ragnar Frisch
/wiki/Jan_Tinbergen | Jan Tinbergen
/wiki/Paul_Samuelson | Paul Samuelson
/wiki/Simon_Kuznets | Simon Kuznets
/wiki/John_Hicks | John Hicks
/wiki/Kenneth_Arrow | Kenneth Arrow
/wiki/Wassily_Leontief | Wassily Leontief
/wiki/Gunnar_Myrdal | Gunnar Myrdal
/wiki/Friedrich_Hayek | Friedrich Hayek
/wiki/Leonid_Kantorovich | Leonid Kantorovich
/wiki/Tjalling_Koopmans | Tjalling Koopmans
/wiki/Milton_Friedman | Milton Friedman
/wiki/Bertil_Ohlin | Bertil Ohlin
/wiki/James_Meade | James Meade
/wiki/Theodore_Schultz | Theodore Schultz
/wiki/Lawrence_Klein | Lawrence Klein
/wiki/James_Tobin | James Tobin
/wiki/George_Stigler | George Stigler
/wiki/Richard_Stone | Richard Stone
/wiki/Franco_Modigliani | Franco Modigliani
/wiki/Robert_Solow | Robert Solow
/wiki/Maurice_Allais | Maurice Allais
/wiki/Trygve_Haavelmo | Trygve Haavelmo
/wiki/Harry_Markowitz | Harry Markowitz
/wiki/Merton_Miller | Merton Miller
/wiki/Ronald_Coase | Ronald Coase
/wiki/Gary_Becker | Gary Becker
/wiki/Robert_Fogel | Robert Fogel
/wiki/Douglass_North | Douglass North
/wiki/John_Harsanyi | John Harsanyi
/wiki/Reinhard_Selten | Reinhard Selten
/wiki/James_Mirrlees | James Mirrlees
/wiki/William_Vickrey | William Vickrey
/wiki/Myron_Scholes | Myron Scholes
/wiki/Amartya_Sen | Amartya Sen
/wiki/Robert_Mundell | Robert Mundell
/wiki/James_Heckman | James Heckman
/wiki/George_Akerlof | George Akerlof
/wiki/Michael_Spence | Michael Spence
/wiki/Joseph_Stiglitz | Joseph Stiglitz
/wiki/Daniel_Kahneman | Daniel Kahneman
/wiki/Clive_Granger | Clive Granger
/wiki/Robert_Aumann | Robert Aumann
/wiki/Thomas_Schelling | Thomas Schelling
/wiki/Edmund_Phelps | Edmund Phelps
/wiki/Leonid_Hurwicz | Leonid Hurwicz
/wiki/Eric_Maskin | Eric Maskin
/wiki/Roger_Myerson | Roger Myerson
/wiki/Paul_Krugman | Paul Krugman
/wiki/Elinor_Ostrom | Elinor Ostrom
/wiki/Peter_Diamond | Peter Diamond
/wiki/Lloyd_Shapley | Lloyd Shapley
/wiki/Eugene_Fama | Eugene Fama
/wiki/Jean_Tirole | Jean Tirole
/wiki/Angus_Deaton | Angus Deaton
/wiki/Richard_Thaler | Richard Thaler
/wiki/William_Nordhaus | William Nordhaus
/wiki/Paul_Romer | Paul Romer
/wiki/Abhijit_Banerjee | Abhijit Banerjee
/wiki/Esther_Duflo | Esther Duflo
/wiki/Michael_Kremer | Michael Kremer
```

---

**EDIT:**

To reduce `Unitet_State` I decided to work with every row separatelly and get only link with third column. But there is problem because HTML uses `colspan` to join columns in two/three rows so in every row this link is in different column.

I decide to find first link in row which matchs `r'^/wiki/[^:]*$'` (to skip link with image `/wiki/File:...`). Because I use `find()` instead of `find_all()` so I find only link to laureat and I don't get link to `United State` which is in next column.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_Memorial_Prize_laureates_in_Economics')
soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_tables = soup.find_all('table')

pattern = re.compile(r'^/wiki/[^:]*$')

for row in all_tables[0].find_all('tr'):
    item = row.find('a', {'href': pattern})
    if item:
        print(item['href'], '|', item['title'])
```